# Understanding a message on CoqIde

Tags: coq

I typed `Eval cbv in id.` in CoqIde and received the message

```
= fun x : ?a => x
 
: ?a -> ?a`
```

What does this mean? What does the question mark mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A name prefixed with a question mark is called a metavariable. It's an unknown term, which may become known later during the typechecking process, but here there is nothing else to typecheck outside of `id`, so it remains unknown.

`id` has an implicit argument. Try the command `About id.` It will tell you that `id` has type `forall a, a -> a`, and also that the first argument `a` is implicit and maximally inserted. When you type `id`, the interpreter expands it to `id _`, inserting an hole `_` for that first argument, and then fresh metavariables `?a` are generated in place of holes.

`id ?a` has type `?a -> ?a` and evaluates to `fun x : ?a => x`.